# A series expansion for $\left(x^2\,B(x,x)\right)^\frac nx$ or $\frac{1}{(Γ(2x))^\frac nx}$ for $0\lt x\le 1, n\in\Bbb N$

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion, radicals, gamma-function, beta-function

[Central Beta function Β(x)](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CentralBetaFunction.html). Imagine we wanted to find a series expansion for $\left(x^2\,B(x,x)\right)^\frac nx, n\in\Bbb N $ which would be particularly difficult because it uses the [Beta function](https://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/Beta/). Let there be the rule that any strategies can be used to find a series expansion for $0\le x\le 1$ as long as the series terms are not too complicated and have some pattern. Here is how I would do it using a [Taylor](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series) [expansion](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1+%2B+0.845569+%28x+-+1%29+%2B+0.156859+%28x+-+1%29%5E2+-+0.00295865+%28x+-+1%29%5E3+%2B+0.000681807+%28x+-+1%29%5E4+-+0.000199655+%28x+-+1%29%5E5+vs+x%21%5E%282%2Fx%29) at x=a which all give beautiful results. One simple and [**amazing expansion would be at x=0**](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=series+x%21%5E%282%2Fx%29+at+x%3D0), but to include all cases, I will use x=a as all cases for $0\lt a\le 1$ have the radius of convergence which works for $0\lt x\le 1$:

$$\left(x^2\,B(x)\right)^\frac 
nx=\left(x^2\,B(x,x)\right)^\frac nx =\frac{x!^\frac{2n}{x}}{Γ(2x)^\frac nx}=Γ^{-\frac nx}(2x)\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\left(\frac{d^n}{dx^n}x!^\frac {2n}x\right)_{x=a}(x-a)^n}{n!}$$

Here comes the problem where I am unsure about the radius of convergence for the usual Taylor series of $Γ(2x) ^{-\frac nx}$. The problem is this steep change due to the x in the denominator of $\left(\frac{(2x)!}{2x}\right)^{-\frac nx}$. If it was the factorial instead of the gamma, there would not be such a small derivative at $x≈0$ which would imply the series representation working. For example here is the graph of $\frac{1}{Γ(2x)^\frac 1x}$ for $n=1$:

[image]

This all relates to the series of $x^\frac 1x$ of which I still do not know the convergence for. It amazingly has an explicit form for the Taylor Series at $x=1$ at [OEIS A008405](http://oeis.org/A008405). How can I do the rest or have a new series?

It does not have to be a Taylor Series.

Please correct me and give me feedback!

Comment: I can't give you a series for $(x^2B(x,x))^\frac{n}{x}$, but I can give you an infinite product formula using again the infinite product expansions for the reciprocal Gamma function. Using those I can give you the infinite series for $\frac{n}{x}\ln(x^2B(x,x))$. Should I write an answer about it?

Comment: @RounakSarkar The goal was to solve an [_Inverse Regularized Beta function_](https://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/InverseBetaRegularized/06/01/02/) version of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4137879/on-completing-the-solution-for-int-01-q-1x-x-dx) which was for fun only. You can totally post the product representation, but then could you please consider a series expansion of $\frac{1}{(Γ(x)) ^\frac nx}, 0\le x\le 1, n\in \Bbb N$? Taylor series, or another option, is always an option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\textstyle\displaystyle{\frac{1}{\Gamma(x)}=x\prod_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1+\frac{x}{n}}{\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^x}}$

$\implies\textstyle\displaystyle{x^2\Gamma^2(x)=\prod_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{2x}}{\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^2}}$

Using the same formula we can get,

$\textstyle\displaystyle{\frac{1}{\Gamma(2x)}=2x\prod_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1+\frac{2x}{n}}{\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{2x}}}$

Finally their ratio would be

$\textstyle\displaystyle{\frac{x^2\Gamma^2(x)}{\Gamma(2x)}}$

$=x^2B(x,x)$

$\textstyle\displaystyle{=2x\prod_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1+\frac{2x}{n}}{\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^2}}$

$\textstyle\displaystyle{\implies\frac{n}{x}\ln(x^2B(x,x))=\frac{n\ln(2x)}{x}+\frac{n}{x}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\ln\left(\frac{n(n+2x)}{(n+x)^2}\right)}$

Obviously this not the infinite sum for the function you wanted but rather the log of it. So I would call this a partial answer.

**Edit**:

Technically you can find the series representation of the function using what I derived previously, but it would produce a messy double summation-

If we take $e$ to be the base on both sides then the $LHS$ would be $(x^2B(x,x))^\frac{n}{x}$ and the $RHS$ would be (using the series representation of $e^x$)-

$\textstyle\displaystyle{(x^2B(x))^\frac{n}{x}=\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{j!}\left(\frac{n\ln(2x)}{x}+\frac{n}{x}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\ln\left(\frac{n(n+2x)}{(n+x)^2}\right)\right)^j}$

---

And for the series representation of $\textstyle\displaystyle{\Gamma(2x)^{-\frac{n}{x}}}$, I will do a similar thing, this time I am going to use weierstrass' formula for the gamma function-

So,
$\Gamma(2x)^{-\frac{n}{x}}=e^{-\frac{n}{x}\ln(\Gamma(2x))}$

$\textstyle\displaystyle{=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k!}\left(-\frac{n}{x}\ln(\Gamma(2x))\right)^k}$

$\textstyle\displaystyle{=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^kn^k}{k!x^k}\ln^k\left(\frac{1}{2xe^{2{\gamma}x}}\prod_{j=1}^{\infty}\frac{e^\frac{2x}{j}}{1+\frac{2x}{j}}\right)}$

$\textstyle\displaystyle{=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^kn^k}{k!x^k}\left(-\ln(2x)-2\gamma x+\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{2x}{j}-\ln\left(1+\frac{2x}{j}\right)\right)\right)^k}$

If I am able to do better than this, then I would add it to the answer.

Comment: If there are no other answers, then I will accept your answer by the end of the bounty. Do you think you could find a series for $\frac{1}{(Γ(2x))^\frac nx}$ for $0\le x\le 1$ which would be an equivalent problem? It can even have nth derivatives etc. Thanks.

Comment: @Tyma Gaidash. I will try today. And I will expand the answer.

Comment: You did it. Please tell me if this series converges to the right value for $0\le x\le1$ and for n a natural number.

Comment: @Tyma Gaidash. For the series representations I produced, there should be absolutely no  constraints for $n$ and $x$ (there are some obvious constraints, but they come from the definition of gamma function and usual fractions) , because in all formulas I used and steps involved really produced no restrictions. But I haven't really checked numerically.

Comment: Also note that $(x^2 B(x))^\frac nx$ is defined at x=0, using a limit, to converge to 0.

Comment: Sorry, there was a more “easily manageable” sum, so the other person won the bounty, but I accepted your answer

Comment: @Tyma Gaidash. Hmm I saw the comments, I am working on the other question of mine currently, that question about $\mathcal{R}$. And I will try to look at working of the sums in this answer numerically, and by the way if you have any idea about progressing in the evaluation of $\mathcal{R}$ then please tell me in the comments.

Comment: Let me look into your question.

Answer (score 1):

- The famous software Mathematica shows that
  \begin{align}
  \left[\frac{1}{\Gamma (2 x)}\right]^{n/x}
  &=\exp \biggl[\frac{n \log (2 x)}{x}+2 \gamma  n-\frac{n \pi ^2}{3} x-\frac{4n \psi''(1)}{3} x^2-\frac{2n \pi ^4}{45}x^3\\
  &\quad -\frac{4n \psi ^{(4)}(1)}{15} x^4-\frac{32 n \pi ^6}{2835}x^5-\frac{8n \psi ^{(6)}(1)}{315}  x^6+O\left(x^7\right)\biggr]
  \end{align}
  and
  \begin{align}
  \biggl[\frac{1}{\Gamma (2 x)}\biggr]^{n/x}
  &=1+2 (\gamma -1) n (x-1)+\frac{1}{3} n \bigl[6 \gamma ^2 n+6 n-6 \gamma  (2 n+1)-\pi ^2+12\bigr] (x-1)^2\\
  &\quad+\frac{1}{3} n \bigl\{4 \gamma ^3 n^2-4 n^2+2 \gamma  \bigl[6 n^2-\bigl(\pi ^2-18\bigr) n+3\bigr]\\
  &\quad-12 \gamma ^2 (n+1) n+2 \bigl(\pi ^2-12\bigr) n+\pi ^2-12-4 \psi''(2)\bigr\}(x-1)^3\\
  &\quad+\frac{1}{90} n \bigl\{60 \gamma ^4 n^3+60 n^3-120 \gamma ^3 (2 n+3) n^2-60 \bigl(\pi ^2-12\bigr) n^2\\
  &\quad+60 \gamma ^2 \bigl[6 n^2-\bigl(\pi ^2-24\bigr) n+9\bigr] n-60 \gamma  \bigl[4 n^3-2 \bigl(\pi ^2-15\bigr) n^2\\
  &\quad+n \bigl(30+4 \psi''(2)-2 \pi ^2\bigr)+3\bigr]+5 n \bigl[\pi ^4-36 \pi ^2+48\bigl(6+\psi''(2)\bigr)\bigr]\\
  &\quad-4 \pi ^4-30 \pi ^2+720+120 \psi''(2)\bigr\}(x-1)^4 +O\bigl((x-1)^5\bigr).
  \end{align}
  These two finite series expansions imply that it should be very difficult to explicitly and simply expand the function $\bigl[\frac{1}{\Gamma (2 x)}\bigr]^{n/x}$ at $x=0,1$ and any other point $x=a\in(0,1)$.
- The function $\frac1{\Gamma(2z)}$ is an entire complex function on $\mathbb{C}$. Therefore, the function $\bigl[\frac1{\Gamma(2z)}\bigr]^{n/z}$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$ is analytic on the punctured complex plane $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$. Accordingly, the function $\bigl[\frac1{\Gamma(2z)}\bigr]^{n/z}$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$ has Taylor's series expansion at any complex point $z_0\ne0$ with a convergent radius $|z_0|$. Consequently, when the function $\bigl[\frac1{\Gamma(2z)}\bigr]^{n/z}$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$ is expanded at $z=1$, its convergent radius is $1$, its convergent disc is $|z-1|<1$. This means that, the Taylor series expansion at $x=1$ of the function $\bigl[\frac1{\Gamma(2x)}\bigr]^{n/x}$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$ is convergent for $|x-1|<1$. By Cauchy's limit theorem, we conclude that the convergent interval is $x\in(0,2]$.

Comment: There are 2 good answers and you have a bit less reputation, so I will give you the bounty and accept the other answer. Without any fancy language, does the series converge for $0<x\le 1$ and for n a natural number? This is a bit more of what I was looking for.

Comment: The function $\frac1{\Gamma(2x)}$ is equal to $0$ at $x=0$; when $x>0$, it is positive; when $x<0$, it is negative. Although the function $\frac1{\Gamma(2x)}$ is analytic at $x=0$, but the function $\bigl[\frac1{\Gamma(2x)}\bigr]^{n/x}$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$ is not continuous at $x=0$. Therefore, the function $\bigl[\frac1{\Gamma(2x)}\bigr]^{n/x}$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$ has no Maclaurin series expansion at $x=0$. Okay? Useful?

Comment: Yes it is useful, but does the second series’s radius of convergence include $x\in (0,1]$?

Comment: @TymaGaidash Yes, my reputation is a bit less. I begun to earn reputations from July this year. Thank a lot for your boundy.

Comment: @TymaGaidash I combined my two answers into one: copied the second answer into the first one and deleted the second answer. Is this the one you suggested to me? If not, let me know to undeleted the second answer.

Comment: This is perfect, so do not change anything unless you want to.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129749/discussion-between-tyma-gaidash-and-qifeng618).